# Disable HTML5 validation on input while enabling it on blur

Tags: javascript, html, validation

The known solution for enabling validity checking on blur is adding the attribute `onblur="this.checkValidity();"`, but how do you prevent HTML5's default behaviour, which is checking an input's validity (for example, an email or a phone) on each keystroke?

Comment: Do you mean type=number or email, for example? You cannot set type=text?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `novalidate` to the form tag to stop the HTML5 validation from kicking in.

```
<form novalidate name="exampleForm" method="post">

</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't `novalidate` prevent `onblur="this.checkValidity();"` from executing?

Comment: You can prevent checking by stopping validation all together with novalidate applied to the form. Otherwise you do not use onblur="this.checkValidity();" but you can create some custom build validation with regex.